# How to install shadcn component library using yarn or npm?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, package, shadcnui

Currently, I'm trying to build a Notion clone using Next.js and shadcn/ui [https://ui.shadcn.com/].

I tried to install shadcn/ui using both npm and yarn but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on my side, the `npx install shadcn-ui@latest` gave me a NodeJS module error so I ended up asking ChatGPT how to install it with npm instead

so try this;

```
npm install -g shadcn-ui
shadcn-ui init
```

if you're using Linux distro(do the same for components as well).

```
sudo npx shadcn-ui@latest init
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g shadcn-ui
shadcn-ui init
```

**Note** Paste both commands(the install and init) on the terminal simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked!! such a relief 

Answer (score 2):

Shadcn/ui is not a typical component library that is distributed through npm or yarn. That being said, you can setup shadcn in your Next.js project by following these commands:

1. Run the `shadcn-ui` init command in your terminal.

```bash
npx shadcn-ui@latest init
```

2. Answer the questions asked in the terminal to configure your `components.json`.

Detailed instructions for further setup can be found here: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/next.

---

Now you can add shadcn/ui components to your project by running commands like the following:

```bash
npx shadcn-ui@latest add button
```

This command will add the `<Button />` component to your project at `components/ui`.